# MySQL INSERT INTO table 1 SELECT table 2 with different column name

Tags: mysql

I have a table `(pdt_1)` in database `(db_1)` and another table `(pdt_2)` in another database `(db_2)`.
I met `pdt_1` and `pdt_2` to find `pdt_1` products not present and published in `pdt_2`.

functional code :

> SELECT * FROM `db_1`.`pdt_1` AS lm 
>   WHERE lm.`product_sku` 
>   NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `product_cip7` FROM `db_2`.`pdt_2`)
>   AND lm.`product_publish`=‘Y'

finally, I need to insert the result of this query in `pdt_2`.

However, the structure of `pdt_1` and `pdt_2` are different.

> Example:
>   
> - columns's names
>   
> - columns's numbers

I also need an auto_increment id for `pdt_1` products inserted into `pdt_2`.

I need help.

NB : sorry for my poor english :(

Comment: When you do an `insert into` the name of the columns doesn't matter. The first field will be filled with the first value and so on

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a new table with just the id and product_sku, try:

```
INSERT INTO new_table # with id and product_sku from first table
SELECT pdt_1.id,
       pdt_1.product_sku
FROM   db_1.pdt_1
       LEFT JOIN db_2.pdt_2
              ON pdt_1.product_sku = pdt_2.product_cip7
WHERE  pdt_2.product_cip7 IS NULL
       AND pdt_1.product_publish = 'Y'
```

Comment: A long time ago in a galaxy far far away ... Thanks for answer ^^

Comment: Can't even remember answering this ^^.
You're welcome.

Comment: @BigDaDDy, make sure to +1 and mark as accepted if this is helpful and solves your problem.